# PHPMailer() se queda cargando la pagina

Tags: php, phpmailer

Mi objetivo es enviar via PHPMailer() un correo a una cuenta de gmail. Puse los parametros y configuraciones adecuadas, pero cuando le doy al Submit, la pagina se queda cargando sin hacer nada, ni si quiera sale ningun error.

PHP:

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';
require 'OAuth.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$Correo->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Username = "correo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("correo@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("correo");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }

  
?>
```

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando en tu máquina o un alojamiento compartido o un VPS? PD: Imagino que sabrás que para hacer uso del servidor SMTP de gmail tienes que crear una contraseña de aplicación, que no te vale la de usuario.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Estoy trabajando desde mi maquina, con un servidor XAMPP, pero tengo una cuenta de correo hecha en un alojamiento y esta configurada en el POP3 de mi cuenta de gmail

Comment: Es posible que el firewall de tu máquina (o de tu ISP) no permita conexiones al exterior desde el proceso de apache o bien tu proveedor podría filtrar conexiones a los puertos relacionados con el correo electrónico (el puerto 25, por ejemplo, suele estar filtrado por defecto en gran número de proveedores). Por cierto, ¿has probado a usar el puerto `587` con el protocolo `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS` en vez de `ssl`?

Comment: @OscarGarciaTenias razon respecto a usar contraseña de aplicacion, la he generado pero no se como aplicarla a mi correo de gmail.

Comment: No afecta en nada a la hora de entrar a google/gmail por página web. La diferencia es que puedes cambiar la contraseña de google sin que deje de funcionar el envío de correos en tu aplicación. Por cierto, ¿con ese cambio se solucionó el problema?